# Repairing a damaged floor tile in the washer/dryer room

Tags: tile

Our floor tile in the washer/dryer room has suffered significant denting, likely due to the weight of the washer and dryer. I've seen people using porcelain ceramic chip fix to mend small cracks in ceramic sinks.

Given this, I'm curious if the same method could be applied to repair a floor tile and how to color match the repaired afterwards.

[image: Damaged floor tile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be VCT (Vinyl Composition Tile) not ceramic. As such, ceramic sink repair methods probably don't apply well.

Color match is all but impossible, given the streak pattern. Standard repair method (these floors are in part used where they may be damaged and require repairs without replacing the whole floor) is to replace the entire damaged tile.

Answer (score 1):

It's a utility room. Unless you're prepping for sale and think this will have a significant impact on sale price, or you're moving out and think the landlord will ding your damage deposit, I'd say go for your chip fix.

Worst thing that could happen is that it won't last very long and you'll have to try something else later, like replacing the whole tile.